# react native not starting metro bundler

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to run a react native code is VS code. I gave the command `npx react-native start` the following use to appear

```
Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native  

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/Siva/Desktop/RHcode/Liba 

Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

The code which I am trying to run was developed in 2020 and I am updating it now with some npm version and package changes.

When i created a demo new project in react native, I gave the command `npx react-native start` I am getting the metro bundler symbol as follows
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

how to overcome this Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Lhu.png

Comment: What do you mean, that is supposed to happen. Use `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` to run on device. The one you’re looking at is the js bundle

Comment: @user16967562 - okay. I am new to react native. What about this image -https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Lhu.png appearing when i create a new project or other project

Comment: Ye that’s totally expected, just follow the guides on react-native site how to make an android emulator. And use `yarn android`. Whenever you want to use the most recent js modifications that you have done you must run `yarn start` it will fetch the automatically. Just let it run on the background or if you use Vscode or other IDE they will show it inside the IDE. Anything that happens on the js side `yarn start` is responsible